# RSpec raises NameErrors for code in subdirectory of /lib

Tags: ruby, rspec, rspec3, ruby-2.2

I have a gem project with the following structure:

```
foo-bar
├── lib
│   └── foo
│       ├── bar
│       │   └── qux.rb
│       └── bar.rb
└── spec
    ├── spec_helper.rb
    └── unit
        ├── baz_spec.rb
        └── qux_spec.rb
```

In `lib/foo`, `bar.rb` defines a module `Foo::Bar`, and inside that, a class `Foo::Bar::Baz`. Inside `lib/foo/bar`, `qux.rb` defines a class `Foo::Bar::Qux`.

`spec_helper.rb` sets up RSpec and Simplecov, and finishes with `require 'foo/bar'`. Both `baz_spec.rb` and `qux_spec.rb` start with `require 'spec_helper'`.

`baz_spec.rb` has the specs for `Foo::Bar::Baz`, and it works fine. `qux_spec.rb`, however, which has the specs for `Foo::Bar::Qux`, fails with:

```
/Users/me/foo-bar/spec/unit/qux_spec.rb:6:in `<module:Bar>': uninitialized constant Foo::Bar::Qux (NameError)
    from /Users/me/foo-bar/spec/unit/qux_spec.rb:4:in `<module:Foo>'
    from /Users/me/foo-bar/spec/unit/qux_spec.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.2.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1226:in `load'
    ...
    (etc.)
```

I've verified that it's not just a typo by moving the code for `Foo::Bar::Baz` out of `lib/foo/bar.rb` and into its own file, `lib/foo/bar/baz.rb`, after which `baz_spec.rb` also stops working.

It also doesn't seem to make a difference whether I declare the class as

```
class Foo::Bar::Qux
  ...
```

or as

```
module Foo
  module Bar
    class Qux
      ...
```

I'm using Ruby 2.2.0 with RSpec 3.2.2 on Mac OS X Yosemite.

Clearly there's something wrong with my `requires`, but as a Ruby novice I'm not seeing it. Any ideas?

Comment: A possible solution depends on what kind of frameworks you are using. So, are you using either Rails or ActiveSupport?

Comment: Neither. Well, I suppose ActiveSupport is in there because I have ActiveJob in my gemspec, but it's not being used yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved: after taking a closer look at the other projects I was [cargo-culting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming) from, I realized I'd misunderstood `require`.

Unlike (apparently) its Rails equivalent, the out-of-the-box [`Kernel.require`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Kernel.html#method-i-require) just loads `.rb` files (and extension libraries). So in the example above, `require 'foo/bar'` doesn't load files from the `foo/bar` directory, it just loads `foo/bar.rb`.

In order to load the files under `foo/bar`, including `qux.rb`, I had to go into `bar.rb` and explicitly load those files at the top of the module declaration:

```
module Foo
  module Bar
    Dir.glob(File.expand_path('../bar/*.rb', __FILE__), &method(:require))

    # ...module declaration continues...
```

Just one of the many scripting-language-heritage pitfalls waiting for those who come to Ruby from other more heavyweight languages, I suppose.

Answer (score 2):

you need to add `foo.rb` file under `./lib` and add require statements for each file in order you want them to get loaded. You can look at sample gem for reference: [dogeify](https://github.com/mhuggins/dogeify/blob/master/lib/dogeify.rb) and an article that walks you through gem creation [build your first gem](https://quickleft.com/blog/engineering-lunch-series-step-by-step-guide-to-building-your-first-ruby-gem/).

Answer (score 1):

If you're using `ActiveSupport` a single line like this will help you:

```
ActiveSupport::Dependencies.autoload_paths << "./lib"
```

If you're now trying to use `Foo::Bar::Qux`, ActiveSupport will look for a file named `foo/bar/qux.rb` inside of the `lib` folder.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using ActiveSupport autoload feature since it introduces dependency which you might not need and also does not give you control of the order in which you files are loaded. Also, consider using ruby's built in autoload feature (http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Module.html#method-i-autoload) if you are using recent version